# The exactness of the sequence involving divisors supported on a finite set of points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This setup can be found across the literature, but the resulting exact sequence has no proper justification. For example, on page 72 of Skorobogatov's *Torsors and rational points*.

Let $C$ be a smooth projective geometrically integral curve over a number field $k$, and let $D$ denote a finite set of closed points of $C$. Let $X$ be the affine curve that is the complement of $D$ and we denote by $\bar{X}$ the usual base change to $\bar{k}$. Then one has an exact sequence

$$1 \rightarrow \bar{k}^* \rightarrow \bar{k}[X]^* \rightarrow \mathrm{Div}_{\bar{D}}(\bar{C}),$$

where the last map is given by taking divisors of a regular function $f \in \bar{k}[X]^*$. I believe the map should look like this

$$f \mapsto \sum_{P \in \bar{D}}\mathrm{ord}_P(f) \cdot P,$$

and clearly and constant function will be mapped to the zero divisor.

**Question.** Why are the constant functions precisely the kernel of the divisor map? Wouldn't an invertible regular function with no zeroes or poles at any of the points in $\bar{D}$ also map to the zero divisor?

In fact, the last term of the sequence can be replaced by $\mathrm{Div}^0_{\bar{D}}(\bar{C})$, the degree zero divisors support on $\bar{D}$, since principal divisors on $\bar{C}$ have degree zero. And so it could look like this
$$1 \rightarrow \bar{k}^* \rightarrow \bar{k}[X]^* \rightarrow \mathrm{Div}^0_{\bar{D}}(\bar{C}).$$

Comment: This is proven in Hartshorne no? The general idea to me is that a function $f\in \overline{k}[X]^*$ defines a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$. We can extend $f$ as a function to all of $C$ since we missed only a finite set of points But then the question becomes "when is the divisor of a regular function on a smooth irreducible curve over an algebraically closed field zero?" and this is done in II.6 o Hartshorne.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician Thanks for the reference and explanation, I'll check it out.